# Can I install Laravel Horizon in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-horizon

My project using laravel 5.3

I want to implement laravel horizon to my project

I searching the reference in documentation laravel 5.3. But I don't find it. It Seems that it only exists in laravel 5.5

Can I install laravel horizion in laravel 5.3?

Comment: upgrade 5.3 to  5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Horizon in laravel 5.3. Horizon have dependencies of Laravel 5.5

In the composer.json of Horizon https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/6fe4cd4af88dde8f411e0454e1e64f773cfe0666/composer.json#L20

```
"illuminate/contracts": "~5.5",
"illuminate/queue": "~5.5",
"illuminate/support": "~5.5",
```

You need to upgrade your application if you want to use Horizon